# Eclipse: exporting configurations from one workspace to another

Tags: java, eclipse

There is a lot of effort involved in configuring the checkstyle/findbug/codestyle etc in a workspace, so repeating the same for another workspace consumes a lot of time.

Is there any way in which I can simply export the preferences from one workspace to another in eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the .settings folder or in .files at the root of the project. You can commit thwm to you SCM. That would make the project know about the IDE, but that's not a problem if settings don't contain absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Some (but unfortunately not all) of the settings you mention can be exported to and imported from an xml file.